# What Should I do when my registrar steal my domain name?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I have registered a .buzz domain and after a week my registrar, GoDaddy, **blocked my account** and changed the who-is info and name servers.

When I got in touch with them, they told me that because they cannot work with my country, I live in Iran for clarification, they have blocked me out and I should wait until the registration period ends like **a full year**, if I want to register it with other registrars, and they will not either let me to **transfer** my domain!!!

As I have found out they have parked my domain and are showing they own ads and there is also a button for getting more information about how to buy it!!!

What should I do now to get back my domain from those thieves?! Please help me. I should also say that they have refunded my money but the problem is that I need my domain name not my money.

Comment: Can you provide us with more information why they did that?

Comment: Sorry buy your need to provide more information, such as what country you live in, and what GoDaddy has said, but ultimately its them whom you need to speak with, as this will likely be opinionated discussion which is something we avoid.

Comment: I tried to clarify the things you mentioned.

Comment: @SimonHayter I have tried to clarify my question. what else do you want to know to remove your flag?! and what do you mean ' ultimately its them whom you need to speak with'? I have peaked with them and have reached the dead end that I've came here and asked this question. they have blocked me out, refunded my money and renamed the domain who-is to their own info forcefully. As I know I must have rights on that domain because I have registered it for the first time. I want to know how should I claim my name.

Comment: If you are in an embargoed country you may simply not be able to have a .buzz domain because no other registrar will let you have it either. So making a complaint is surely a waste of time?

Comment: @SimonHayter do hear me?! What exactly don't you understand?! ask me and I will mention it. You just know how to put on hold questions?! come and answer me. WHAT DONT YOU UNDERSTAND? my question is very simple, "What should I do when my registrar steal my domain name?"

Comment: Yes, I hear you loud and clear! you need to speak to GoDaddy, or a solicitor. When you register a domain you are subject to their terms and conditions, failure to comply with the rules then they are obligated by ICANN to take action, in this case they have... you have no legal stance since you failed to read the terms and conditions, reopening the question will not provide any more information on the subject, or will anybody be able resolve the issue for you.

Comment: Why do you think you are omniscience @SimonHayter?! Let the people read the question and maybe they know the answer? No one will consider you dumb and stupid if you don't know answers to some questions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what country you are in, however, in the U.S. they would be required to refund your money. Contact them and try and get a refund. You should be trying everything you can do to give them opportunity to make this matter right. Be kind and polite when dealing with them.

*What to do if this does not work?*

I cannot speak to what is required in your country, however, I will discuss what to do in the U.S.

If GoDaddy does not return your payment, they would have to prove that you obtained services through fraudulent means in order to have a defense or that you were unreasonable in your demands. They would also have to prove that they acted reasonably and established an agreement with you to refund your money.

Their responsibility to you is to appropriately provide services and to have processes and/or procedures to prevent disappointment. They are then responsible to make right any harm when the company has acted in error. Failing to do this would be simple theft.

Given that, and assuming that they have not refunded your payment, you can file a small claims law suit. These can be filed by you for a small fee and do not require a lawyer. I always recommend talking to a lawyer prior to filing. There are plenty of lawyers that will help you with free advice and give you a strategy for court. Small claims court can not only award your payment, but punitive payments when companies fail to respond appropriately. If you make a claim including the request for punitive charges and if GoDaddy does not show up, you will get a default judgement.

*This can be fun!* I canceled my cable services due to the horrible cable company that had the monopoly in my area. The fact of the matter was their services was poor and not worth the money charged. I took 5 consecutive Fridays off from work in order to return their cable box. I was a consultant at the time and taking time off cost significant money in earnings. The Saturday after the 5th Friday they did not show up, I was served with a law suit for the theft of their equipment. As a company, I had a lawyer and called him quickly. I filed a counter suit at 8:30 Monday morning.

Long story short, the Judge yelled at the cable company for quite a while. He made them face me and apologize. When they mumbled, he yelled again and made them speak into the microphone. It is now in the court record. He dismissed their suit and awarded the earnings I lost the 5 days waiting, plus court costs and loss of earnings going to court, plus punitive payment required to be paid before leaving court. They had to write a check in front of the judge and enter it as a matter of record with the court secretary before they could leave. This meant that someone have to bring a check from the office (which was not close) and they had to wait. Lawyers were made to sit in front of the judge waiting. Great fun!!

Comment: They have refunded the money but what I need is my domain name not my money. the domain is now registered to GoDaddy and I can not register it with other registrars.

Comment: @EhsanAfzali In some way you are stuck. However, someone at another registrar can do something creative I am sure. It is a matter of not dealing with a form or low level tech support who must follow procedures. Perhaps a more local registrar and talking to someone higher up the food chain.