# My registrar blocked my account and will not release my domain name. How should I register it with other registrars?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I have registered a .buzz domain and after a week my registrar, **blocked my account** and changed the who-is info and name servers.

When I got in touch with them, they told me that because they cannot work with my country, I live in Iran for clarification, they have blocked me out and I should wait until the registration period ends like **a full year**, if I want to register it with other registrars, and they will not either let me to **transfer** my domain!!!

As I have found out they have parked my domain and are showing they own ads and there is also a button for getting more information about how to buy it!!!

What should I do now to get back my domain from them?! I should have some rights on that domain anew because I have registered it for the first time, and its not seems logical that they can hold my domain name just because they don't want to work with me. Please help me. I should also say that they have refunded my money but the problem is that I need my domain name not my money.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Should I do when my registrar steal my domain name?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87170/what-should-i-do-when-my-registrar-steal-my-domain-name)

Comment: @closetnoc yes, but someone put that on hold and I don't know why he doesn't reply so I created a new one

Comment: Perhaps the mod can look at the original question for you.

Comment: I have flagged it two days ago but nothing happened.

Comment: I hate to break it to you Ehsan, but making two questions extremely similar to each other on here will not get you better answers to your domain issues.

Comment: You should have gotten a reply. To the mods defense, there is a lot that they have to watch and sometimes they miss something - not too often, but we are all human after all.

Comment: Agreed. @Mike is right. It just makes the mods mad and people tend to skip over them. We all want to help - mods included. I am not sure how to help you except to see if there is a registry that can help get your domain name out of jail for you. GoDaddy is in the business to make money off of registrations so I am sure this was necessary for some reason which can be worked around with an imaginative partner. I just do not know what I can tell you to help.

Comment: @EhsanAfzali The commentators above are correct - I'm not the mod in question, but asking the same question twice isn't going to help, particularly for an issue in regards to the policies of a third-party for which users here have no control over. You can perhaps file a [Registrar Compliance Complaint](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/registrars-2013-05-03-en) with ICANN, continue to request that they delete the domain, and monitor it in case they do - sometimes they'll release it early in cases like this and it might possibly be registered elsewhere.

Comment: If you are in an embargoed country you may simply not be able to have a .buzz domain because no other registrar will let you have it either. So making a complaint is surely a waste of time?